# DateTime Stamp in WebSql

Tags: datetime, web-sql, jaydata

I am using `websql database` and also using `JayData Context` in that table i have a column with data type `'type':'Edm.DateTime'`I insert date like this

```
var date = new Date();
.......
_context.FoodLog.add({Quantity:quant,TotalCalories:calcories,DateTime:date,FoodItem:foods,User:user});
```

it store in database like in this format `1384000575450` but i check this date by online time converter then it is not the date of today

How to set todays date so it stores correctly in `webSql`

Answer (score 0):

Unix time is in seconds and your ts is in ms so divide it by 1000